# PYTHON: NameError: name "..." is not defined, mas eu defini a função

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da cobrinha usando Python. Utilizei a biblioteca tkinter e, para registrar o pressionamento de uma tecla, eu utilizei a função bind() que executa um evento após uma tecla ser pressionada.
Eu defini na mesma classe várias funções para serem utilizadas no bind, porém quando eu coloco o bind() no código, recebo o seguinte erro:

> NameError: name 'move_up' is not defined

Segue o código:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tamanho = [0, 0, 20, 20]
        self.vel = [0,0,0,0]

    def create_snake(self):
        self.snake = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.tamanho , fill='white')
        while True:
            self.tamanho = [self.tamanho[0]+ self.vel[0], self.tamanho[1]+self.vel[1], self.tamanho[2] + self.vel[2], self.tamanho[3] +self.vel[3] ]
            print(self.tamanho[0])
            self.canvas.delete('all')
            self.snake = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.tamanho , fill='white')
            self.window.after(70)
            self.window.update_idletasks()
            self.window.update()
            self.window.bind("<Up>", move_up)
            self.window.bind("<Down>", move_down)
            self.window.bind("<Right>", move_right)
            self.window.bind("<Left>", move_left)  

    def move_right(self, event):
        self.vel = [20,0,20,0]

    def move_down(self, event):
        self.vel = [0, 20, 0, 20]

    def move_left(self, event):
        self.vel = [-20, 0, -20, 0]

    def move_up(self, event):
        self.vel = [0, -20, 0, -20]

t = Game()
t.create_snake()
```

Eu não consigo entender por qual motivo a função não é reconhecida se eu já defini ela dentro da mesma classe. Como corrijo isso?

Answer (score 2):

Este erro está sendo gerado porque de fato não existe uma função chamada `move_up`. O que você quer chamar é um método de um objeto, logo, você deve passar a instância `self` ao chamar a função, dessa forma:

```
        # Código ...

        self.window.bind("<Up>", self.move_up)
        self.window.bind("<Down>", self.move_down)
        self.window.bind("<Right>", self.move_right)
        self.window.bind("<Left>", self.move_left)  

        # Código ...
```

Não só para métodos, como também para atributos. Se você por exemplo criar uma classe e um método dessa forma:

```
class Pessoa:
    nome = 'Lucas'

    def hello(self):
        print("Olá, meu nome é %s."%nome)
```

Não vai funcionar, porque você não está passando a instância ao tentar utilizar o atributo. Sempre que você for utilizar um atributo ou método, lembre-se de passar a referência daquele dado.

Comment: NOSSA! MUITO OBRIGADO